# AWS ELB vs Service Registry

Tags: microservices, amazon-elb, netflix-eureka, service-discovery, istio

In microservices architecture, It is not a good practice to hardcode the URLs of services in the code or in the configs as that may change. To achieve this we use service discovery pattern. But the same can be achieved using the AWS ELB, Once I register my services with ELB and if I hardcode the URL of it then there is no regression of changing the Ip of the service as the ELB URL remains same.

So, What is the difference between **hardcoding the AWS ELB URL in the code config** and using **service registry tools such as Eureka, Istio**?

Answer (score 1):

I see two major different of having service discovery via tools like  Eureka, Istio or by AWS ELB

1. In using AWS ELB, you are kind of dependent or cloud implementation or cloud provider.
   Your deployment is now coupled with Cloud provide. Now, in future if you have to change the cloud (say you want to move on Azure for some reason) then migration would lead to some extra effort as you need to setup the couter part of cloud service discovery on new cloud. But in case of directly using Eureka or istio you just need to deploy your artifacts and corresponding configuration on new cloud platform.
2. The second difference is how internally client is able to discover the target services.

**There are two patterns for service discovery:**

Eureka, Istio is **Client-side service discovery**
The client talks directly to the service registry and gets the complete address (host and port) of service to be called. So, in the end, the client knows the host and port of service and the client is the one who makes a final request to targeted service, therefore, this is called client-side discovery.

AWS ELB **is Server-side service discovery**
The client talks to a Load Balancer (or router). Router internally discovers the address of service via Service registry and then make a call further to target service.

*Major difference* –

- The client never got to know the address of the target service or client never needs to know the target service details.
- The client code becomes simpler as it does not have to deal with service discovery.

Answer (score 0):

Service Registry like Eureka is an example of client-side service discovery. 
AWS ELB represents server-side service discovery.

Please go through - https://microservices.io/patterns/service-registry.html for a deep dive.